# Visiblity/show and hidden/hide clases foundation

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

In foundation please explain it with any good example. I couldn't understand the difference from [**zurb-foundation documentation**](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html).

1) `hidden-for-*` vs `hide-for-*`.

2) `visible-for-*` vs `show-for-*`.

Answer (score 1):

It gave a pretty good explanation, I think, with this quote:

> Adding display: none to an element will prevent screen readers from
>   reading it. However, there are techniques to hide content while still
>   making it readable by screen readers.

If I wanted to show/hide a piece of content specifically for screen readers, I would use `hide-for-*` and `show-for-*`.

---

`hidden-for-*` and `visible-for-*` Are for regular uses. Hiding and showing content based on screen size for all users. For example, changing the size of a header.

`hide-for-*` and `show-for-*` Are for accessibility uses. Hiding and showing content based on screen-size specifically for screen-readers. For example, changing the size of clickable buttons or showing some meta information because it would be difficult to otherwise access that information from a screen-reader.